# Laravel 5, how to make a general model handler for uploads?

Tags: laravel-5, model, upload

In my current project based on Laravel 5.4 I have many Models which are using uploaded documents as relation.

I want to avoid to make for each model a separate relational class like:

```
Product -> hasMany(Photos)
User    -> hasOne(AvatarImage)
Ticket  -> hasMany(Documents)
```

and I try to figure out how could I have a main class let's call `Document` model which could interact with many other models.

Is there a how to? for this case

Answer (score 0):

Look into Laravel's polymorphic relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

It allows you to store a related models type and id on the `Document` model. This way any other model can for a hasOne or hasMany relationship to `Document`.